# How do I run this php telegram bot code rcorrectly?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I have some pure php code to launch a bot in Telegram :

```
<?php
const TOKEN = "<some token>";

$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . TOKEN . '/getUpdates';

$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY);
// echo $response;
// var_dump($response);

$lastUpdateId = 934084308;

$params = [
    'offset' => $lastUpdateId + 1
];

$output = $url . '?' . http_build_query[$params];

echo $output;

if ($response['ok']) {
    foreach ($response['result'] as $update) {
        echo $update['message']['text'];
    }
}
```

And the error I get is as follows:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant http_build_query - assumed 'http_build_query' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\test_bot\bot.php on line 20
>
> Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\test_bot\bot.php on line 20
>   https://api.telegram.org/bot756467164:AAFXMfZI1N6OBQ-dCiPRAFpE7pOd-i1spTg/getUpdates?t/starthi!Im here

What's wrong about my code as I studied `http_build_query` function and do not see any error in there?

Comment: Function calls use (), not [] … [] accesses elements in an array or characters in a string.

Comment: Is that your real token...?

Answer (score 1):

Change

`http_build_query[$params];`

to

`http_build_query($params);`

Comment: Removing the token won't help, as it will be still visible in the revision. OP should generate a new token

Comment: @DarkBee Agreed, I have removed it for all intents and purposes, but they shouldn't have posted in the first place